# How to perform unsupervised anomaly detection from log file with mostly textual data?

Tags: neural-networks, machine-learning, natural-language-processing, word2vec, anomaly-detection

I have a log file of the format,

> Index, Date, Timestamp, Module, App, Context, Session, Verbosity level, Description

The log file can be considered as a master log, which consists of individual logs from several modules constituting a distributed system. The individual log can be identified using the corresponding Module+App+Context tags. The verbosity level(Info, Warn, Error, …) and the descriptions(system generated + print statements added by developers) contain further information on the log events necessary for debugging. I need to perform an **unsupervised anomaly detection** with the log file as input. The output should be the functionality and timestamp of the identified anomalies.

Since the log is mostly textual, I plan to use NLP algorithm (Bag of words/TF-IDF) to convert the data into word vectors and then perform a generative learning method to identify the normal pattern. Can someone suggest if my approach in the right direction? Which headers of the log file would be relevant for the word-vector representation and further analysis?